# How can I Update My isFetching Props to get Activity Spinner working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making an Async API call from a React native Component. I would like to show my Activity Spinner until I get a response back. The setProps() function is deprecated. I know that I can pass a prop down from the AddressForm.js Parent Element when I render it. But how can I change the state of the parent element once I get a response to stop the Spinner Here is my code:

Address Form:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { 
 View, 
 StyleSheet, 
 } from 'react-native';

 import { 
 FormLabel, 
FormInput, 
Button,
} from 'react-native-elements'

import InfoButton from './InfoButton';

export default class AddressForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      line1: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zip: '',
      isFetching: false,
    };
}

handleLine1 = (text) => {
    this.setState({ line1: text })      
}
handleCity = (text) => {
    this.setState({ city: text })
}
handleState = (text) => {
    this.setState({state: text })
}
handleZip = (text) => {
    this.setState({ zip: text })
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
            <FormLabel>Address Line 1</FormLabel>
            <FormInput 
                onChangeText={this.handleLine1}
            />
            <FormLabel>City</FormLabel>
            <FormInput 
                onChangeText={this.handleCity}
            />
            <FormLabel>State</FormLabel>
            <FormInput 
                onChangeText={this.handleState}
            />
            <FormLabel>Zip</FormLabel>
            <FormInput 
                onChangeText={this.handleZip}
            />
            <InfoButton // This is the child component
                info={this.state} 
                API_KEY={this.props.API_KEY} 
                isFetching={this.state.isFetching}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Here is the child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
View,
ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native'

import { 
 Button,
} from 'react-native-elements'


export default class InfoButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getVoterInfo = this.getVoterInfo.bind(this);
}

getVoterInfo(){
    this.setProps({ isFetching: true}, () => console.log('Fetching Data: ' +this.props.isFetching));
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=' + API_KEY + '&address='  + newLine1 + '%20' + newCity + '%20' + newState + '%20')
    .then((data) => {
        results = data.json()
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({data});
        this.setProps({ isFetching:false });
        console.log(this.state.data);
        console.log('Ended Fetch:' + this.props.isFetching);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })  
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.state);
    API_KEY = this.props.API_KEY;
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    //Logic adds '%20' in place of spaces in address fields in order to correctly query the API 
    newLine1 = (this.props.info.line1.split(' ').join('%20'));
    newCity = (this.props.info.city.split(' ').join('%20'));
    newState = (this.props.info.state.split(' ').join('%20'));
    // console.log(newLine1);
}


render() {
    const myButton = 
    <Button
        raised
        icon={{name: 'cached'}}
        title="Get Info"
        onPress={this.getVoterInfo}
    />
    const spinner = <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />

    return (
        <View>
        {this.props.isFetching === true ? spinner : myButton}
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that you need to pass a function to your child component, via props, which will be called when you're done fetching in your child component.

```
<InfoButton // This is the child component
    info={this.state} 
    API_KEY={this.props.API_KEY}
    onFetchStart={() => {
      this.setState({isFetching: true});
    }}
    onFetchEnd={() => {
      this.setState({isFetching: false});
    }}
/>
```

We pass here two functions, to know when we begin fetching and when we end.

In your InfoButton component, all you need to do is call these functions when needed, like that for example :

```
getVoterInfo(){
    this.setState({ isFetching: true});
    this.props.onFetchStart(); // HERE WE TELL OUR PARENT THAT OUR FETCHING HAS STARTED
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=' + API_KEY + '&address='  + newLine1 + '%20' + newCity + '%20' + newState + '%20')
    .then((data) => {
        results = data.json()
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({data, isFetching: false});
        this.props.onFetchEnd(); // HERE WE TELL OUR PARENT THAT OUR FETCHING HAS ENDED
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })  
}
```

And remember to use `this.state.isFetching` instead of `this.props.isFetching` in your InfoButton component !